# "pre_option_upload_url_path" Filter No Longer Firing in WordPress 4.7

Tags: wordpress, add-filter

I have the below filter added to my theme's functions.php file:

```
function cdn_upload_url() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
            return 'http://d24fxnpb2c5viy.cloudfront.net';
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_option_upload_url_path', 'cdn_upload_url' , 10);
```

After upgrading to WordPress 4.7, this filter no longer fires.

Do `pre_option_{option}` filters no longer work in 4.7?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: We have the same problem. Did you have any solution to this?

Comment: I did actually ... The solution that worked for me in WP 4.7

    ```add_filter('upload_dir', 'cdn_upload_url');
    function cdn_upload_url($args)
    {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        $args['baseurl'] = 'https://your-awesome-cdn.net/wp-content/uploads';
    }
    return $args;
    }```

Comment: `if (!is_admin())` is important but you may want to check user roles as well. If you have an organization with editors, you may not want to have them reading from the CDN URL either since it takes a while for assets to propagate to a CDN

Comment: Gist here:
[link]https://gist.github.com/Fliktrax/dfcf7e2a0d2d263aeed9fe4fbd7d45a1

Comment: Updated Gist with user roles you "don't"  want  to URL swap:
[link] https://gist.github.com/Fliktrax/9c5f79ad038094a2684ccd14f28fe967

Answer (score 1):

There is a hidden admin page where you can find all the options:

```
http://localhost/wp-admin/options.php
```

Find the `upload_url_path` option and set a value.

[image]

---

Note:

After you give it value, then the "Store uploads in this folder" which is the `upload_path`, and "Full URL path to files" which is the `upload_url_path` options will also appear on the Media Settings page:

```
http://localhost/wp-admin/options-media.php
```

[image]